# Auto update Google Slide embedded image

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Slide that has an embedded image in it that I get from a public URL. I'd like for that image to automatically update every day at a specific time, rather than me having to open the slide and replace the image by URL every day.

Here's the code I tried to use, (replacing the placeholders 'SLIDE_ID' and 'IMAGE_URL' with the actual values) but it's not working.

```
function updateEmbeddedImage() {
  // Get the slide ID and the image URL
  var slideId = "SLIDE_ID";
  var imageUrl = "IMAGE_URL";

  // Open the slide and get the existing image
  var slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideId);
  var existingImage = slide.getImages()[0];
  
  // Replace the existing image with the new image
  var newImage = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
  slide.replaceImage(existingImage, newImage);
}

// Set a time-based trigger to run the script every day at a specific time
function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateEmbeddedImage")
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(9)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}
```

I get the message:

> Error
> Exception: Not found
> updateEmbeddedImage   @ Code.gs:7

Answer (score 0):

**Issue in the OP code:**

`Error Exception: Not found updateEmbeddedImage @ Code.gs:7`. I can only speculate that the code included in the question is NOT the code that is in `code.gs`, since this error means that the script can't find a specific function.

In any event, the OP's code as written is OK.

But there are major flaws in the code:

**`var existingImage = slide.getImages()[0];`**

- `getImages()` is a `slide` method. But `slide` is (in this case) the variable used to describe the presentation.
- To get the slides use `getSlides()`; like `var slides = slide.getSlides()`. Even then you also have to nominate a specific slide, such as slides[0], or slides[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llb0Q.jpg).
- the `[0]` at the of the line has no effect.

**`slide.replaceImage(existingImage, newImage);`**

- There is no method `replaceImage`
- There **is** a `replaceImage` Request that is part of the Google Slides API but this is irrelevant in this context.

**Replacing the image url**

- Google Slides has an `image` method specifically designed to do this
- `replace(imageUrl)`: Replaces this image with another image downloaded from the provided URL.

**The OP's trigger code can be re-used.**

---

**Revised `updateEmbeddedImage`**

```
function updateEmbeddedImage() {
  // Get the slide ID and the image URL
  var slideId = "<<insert slideID>>"
  var imageUrl = "<<insert imageurl>"

  // Open the slide and get the existing image
  var slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideId)

  // assume the image is on slide#2 (zero-based=1)
  var slides = slide.getSlides()
  var targetSlide = slides[1]

  // assume there is on one image on this slide
  var images = targetSlide.getImages()
  
  // replace the source URL
  images[0].replace(imageUrl)
  
}
```

---

**Code alternative**

The OP's script requires that the source url must be hard coded into the script. This is inconvenient as well as error-prone.

- this script in this answer should be bound to a Spreadsheet.
- the Source URL should be entered in Column B.
- Column A can contain an `image()` formula to show the image (and also confirm the url is valid).
- the script returns **all** the slides (`getSlides()`) but assumes the embedded image is on the second slide.
- The script gets **all** the images (`getImages()`) on that slide but assumes that the image to be replaced is the first image on the slide.
- The existing SourceURL is returned with `.getSourceUrl()`
- The new SourceURL is obtained from the spreadsheet

  - There is error checking to make sure that the existing SourceURL could be found AND that it wasn't the last URL on the spreadsheet.

---

```
// this script is bound to the spreadsheet containing the urls of the images.
// URL are in column B, beginning in row 1
// Image() formula is in Column A to display the image associated with the url
// to automatically update every day at a specific time, create a Time driven Installatble trigger.
function replaceurl() {

  // get the slide
  var slideId = "<<insert ID>>"
  var slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideId)

  // get the slides; assume the embedded image is on the second slide
  var slides = slide.getSlides()
  var targetSlide = slides[1]

  // get images
  // assume that image to replace is the first image on the slide
  var images = targetSlide.getImages()

  // get the source url of the existing image
  var existingSourceURL = images[0].getSourceUrl()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Existing Source URL: "+existingSourceURL)

  // get the source url of the next image in the spreadsheet
  // slide urls are in column B
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SlideDetails")
  var urlRange = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow())
  Logger.log("DEBUG: URL Range: "+urlRange.getA1Notation())
  // get the values and flatten to return a 1D array
  var urlValues = urlRange.getValues().flat()
  Logger.log(urlValues) //DEBUG
  // get the number of URLs on the spreadsheet
  var valCount = urlValues.length
  Logger.log("DEBUG: # of values in the sheet: "+valCount)

  // find the index of the existing source url (zero-based)
  var existingIdx = urlValues.indexOf(existingSourceURL)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Index of existing url: "+existingIdx);

  // test if idx of existing url wasn't found AND
  // test if idx of existing url = num of urls
  // indexOf returns -1 if idx is not found
  if (existingIdx != -1 && existingIdx != (valCount-1)){
    // existing Source URL was found and the idx isn't greater than number of urls on the list
    // new Source URL is next on the list
    var newSourceURL = urlValues[existingIdx+1]
    Logger.log("DEBUG: new source url: "+newSourceURL)

    // replace the source URL
    images[0].replace(newSourceURL)
  }
  else{
    // don't change or replace the url
    // don't replace the url
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Image not changed because existing URL is either not found OR was last in the list")
  }
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Done")
}
```

---

**Spreadsheet Layout**

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: I should clarify my objective. I have a Google Slide that is displayed on a "Welcome" screen in our lobby. In that slide is a jpg of a 5 day weather forecast that I pickup from a URL from one of our local TV stations. As it works now,every day I have to manually open the slide, select the image, Replace image > By URL and paste the URL to the image which will cause the Google Slide to re-download the image. The URL is static, the filename never changes.

Comment: Refer updates in answer with a new script: **Revised `updateEmbeddedImage`**. I've tested this and it works as expected.